# Update the navigation menu when changing the display conditions of icons in BottomNavigationBarItem in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a navigation menu that I made for a test application, there are some tabs that I want to hide if I am not logged into the application. After logging in, these tabs should appear. The problem is that after logging in, I go to the desired page and I don't see all the navigation menu icons. For them to appear, I need to click on one of the available icons (only 2 icons are available for authorization) and only then the navigation menu will be updated and everything will be as it should be. All 6 icons will be visible! Can someone help me with this? Here I described the problem with the code that I am using. I would be grateful for any help.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/object_main/Status.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/seals/Seals_List.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/Setting_glob.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/add_seals/JsonAddSeals.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/user_page/page.dart';
import  'package:flutter_app_seals/model/setting/globalvar.dart' as global;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_aes_ecb_pkcs5/flutter_aes_ecb_pkcs5.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


void main() => runApp(Main_Page());


class Main_Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
        home:  HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
var test;
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Ви впевнині?'),
        content: new Text('Ви хочете вийти з додатку',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child:
            Text("Ні",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 40),
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
            child: Text("Так",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ) ??
        false;
  }


  int _pageIndex = 0;
  PageController _pageController;

  List<Widget> tabPages = [
    Login(),
    Setting(),
    UserPage(),
    Status_Obj(),
    Status_Seals(),
    Add_Seals(),
  ] ;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _pageIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          showSelectedLabels: true,   // <-- HERE
          showUnselectedLabels: true, // <-- AND
          currentIndex: _pageIndex,
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            new BottomNavigationBarItem( icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings_outlined), title: Text(" Вхід"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text("Налаштування"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
            if( global.nameUser ?.isNotEmpty == true)...[
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin), title: Text("Користувач"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("Пломбування"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code), title: Text("Пломби"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add_outlined), title: Text("Акт приймання"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
            ]

          ],

        ),
        body: PageView(
          children: tabPages,
          onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
          controller: _pageController,
        ),
      ),
    );



  }
  void onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      this._pageIndex = page;
    });
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    this._pageController.animateToPage(index,duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }
}


class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new LoginPage(
            storage: Storage()
        )
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final Storage storage;

  LoginPage({Key key, @required this.storage}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  //Info about users
  String state;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.storage.readData().then((String value) {
      setState(() {
        global.urlVar = value;
      });
    });
  }

  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.white],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
        ),
        child: _isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            headerSection(),
            textSection(),
            buttonSection(),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  signIn(String login, pass) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var AESLogin = login;
    var AESpass = pass;
    //generate a 16-byte random key
    var key = '11111';

    print(key);
    //encrypt
    var encryptLogin = await FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.encryptString(AESLogin, key);
    var encryptPass = await FlutterAesEcbPkcs5.encryptString(AESpass, key);




    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);


    String url = global.urlVar + "/auth_user";

    Map map = {
      "login": encryptLogin,
      "pass": encryptPass
    };

    HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');

    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();


    var responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();

    Map jsonResponse = json.decode(responseBody);

    print(jsonResponse);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (jsonResponse['message'] ==
          '200') { //if( jsonResponse['message'] == '200') {
        setState(() {



          _isLoading = false;


        });

        global.nameUser = jsonResponse['name'];
        global.dataArea = jsonResponse['data_area'];

        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserPage()),
        );
      }
      else {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Error_Auth()),
        );
      }
    }

    else   {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Container buttonSection() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 40.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: emailController.text == "" || passwordController.text == "" ? null : () {
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = true;
          });
          signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
        },
        elevation: 0.0,
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: Text("Авторизація", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70)),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  final TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  Container textSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: emailController,
            cursorColor: Colors.white,

            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.login, color: Colors.white70),
              hintText: "Логін",
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            cursorColor: Colors.white,
            obscureText: true,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.white70),
              hintText: "Пароль",
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),

    );
  }

  Container headerSection() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
      child: Text("Пломби",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70,
              fontSize: 40.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    );
  }
}
class Error_Auth extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Помилка при авторизації'),
      content:
      Text('Повторити спробу авторизації'),
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          textColor: Color(0xFF6200EE),
          onPressed: () => SystemNavigator.pop(),
          child: Text('Ні'),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          textColor: Color(0xFF6200EE),
          onPressed: () {  Navigator.push(
            context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
          );
          },
          child: Text('Так'),
        ),
      ],
    );
    return Scaffold(
        body:dialog
    );
  }
}

class Storage {
  Future<String> get localPath async {
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return dir.path;
  }

  Future<File> get localFile async {
    final path = await localPath;
    return File('$path/db.txt');
  }

  Future<String> readData() async {
    try {
      final file = await localFile;
      String body = await file.readAsString();

      return body;
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeData(String data) async {
    final file = await localFile;
    return file.writeAsString("$data");
  }
}
```

In this part of the code I am automated and if the status code is 200, then I parse the Jason and add a name for the variable global.nameUser. And in the navigation menu I check if it is not zero then show all the icons of the navigation menu. But the first time it doesn't work. I have clicked on this menu again and only then it will work.

```html
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (jsonResponse['message'] ==
          '200') { //if( jsonResponse['message'] == '200') {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        global.nameUser = jsonResponse['name'];
        global.dataArea = jsonResponse['data_area'];

        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserPage()),
        );
      }
```

Check the navigation menu which icons to display!

```html
items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            new BottomNavigationBarItem( icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings_outlined), title: Text(" Вхід"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text("Налаштування"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
            if( global.nameUser ?.isNotEmpty == true)...[
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin), title: Text("Користувач"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("Пломбування"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code), title: Text("Пломби"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add_outlined), title: Text("Акт приймання"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
            ]

          ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is not re built after logging in the user, that is why your nav bar is not updated. When you click on the button it refreshes and correctly displays the new elements.

Instead of using a global variable you could look into a state management package in order to make the logged-in user available throughout your app. ([article](https://pub.dev/packages/get) for getx the simplest one out there)

If this is simply a prototype and you want some quick and dirty, I guess you could trigger a reload of your app once a user logs in by wrapping your app with a widget that exposes a rebuild method. ([article](https://hillel.dev/2018/08/15/flutter-how-to-rebuild-the-entire-app-to-change-the-theme-or-locale/))

EDIT: Example with Getx:

```
class UserController extends GetxController {
  var nameUser = "".obs;

  void setName(String str) => nameUser = str;
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserController c = Get.put(UserController());

  @override
  Widget build(context)
      ...
          Obx(() => /// You are watching your controller
             ...
             items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
             if( c.nameUser.isNotEmpty)...[
                ...
             ]
          )))   
      ...


class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  // You can ask Get to find a Controller that is being used by another page and redirect you to it.
  final UserController c = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(context){
      ...
      onPressed: () => c.setName(username);
  }
}
```

Comment: could you help me with this rotation, I'm just new to flutter and very confused with this problem, I can not solve it for a week, even the class Login page moved to the mine. I will be grateful for the help)

Comment: I added an example with getx tell me if its not clear

Comment: The problem is coming from the fact that a Widget is only rebuilt when calling setState either directly or from his parents. In your case the data is correctly updated but your widget is not rebuilt because you did not tell you app so. To simplify the state management I would advise you to start reading about getx or any other statemanamenent package

Comment: i added "get" to pubspec.yaml and also do import to main. And now I need to wrap HomePage in GetxController ?? I understood that. But I want you to pay attention to the fact that after authorization I assign the username to global.nameUser. This variable is in a second file of type var (library my_prj.globals;)

Comment: Yes you correctly assigned it but you do not refresh the display. Look at your bottomnavigation you are using the setState function in order to trigger a refresh in addition to assigning the new index. It comes a little bit trickier when refreshing from different screens, here comes in action the state management package

Comment: I am very grateful for your help, but I do not have enough experience to understand you completely)) you can explain a little more, I am just a beginner and spent a lot of time on this problem, and you are the first who can at least explain to me what problem)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233755/discussion-between-wapazz-and--).

Comment: hello, could you look at my code again, I try to get out of this application by your method, but there is an error) thank you)

Comment: Hi, I don't want to bother you, but I can still count on your help ??